# startIntentSenderForResult is deprecated and I want a call to onActivityResult callback in my fragment

Tags: android, in-app-update

I am implementing [in-app update](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) in Android in my app using fragment. In order to get a callback in onActivityResult in my fragment, I should call update as follow using [AppUpdateManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateManager) :

```
appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
            info.result,
            AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
            fragment::startIntentSenderForResult,
            flexibleAppUpdateReqCode
        )
```

**startIntentSenderForResult** is deprecated. What is the new solution for that? So I can get a call to onActivityResult callback in my fragment.